# Why isn'y my Tkinter window opening?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
import Tkinter
import random

class die:
    def __init__(self,dieNum,frame,game):
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(frame,
          text = ' ',
          command = self.rollDie,
          font = ('Garamond', 30),
          bg = 'white')
        self.button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.game = game
        self.value = ' '
        self.num = dieNum
    def rollDie(self):
        if self.value == ' ':
            self.button.config(text = self.game.Player)
            self.value = self.game.Player
            self.game(self.num)

class DiceRoller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameWin = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.gameFrame = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.dice = [  ]
        self.Row1 = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        for i in range(1):
            self.dice.append(die(i,self.Row1,self))
        self.Row2 = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        for i in range(2):
            self.dice.append(die(i,self.Row2,self))
        self.Row3 = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        for i in range(3):
            self.dice.append(die(i,self.Row3,self))

        self.topFrame = Tkinter.Frame(self.gameWin)
        self.rollBtn = Tkinter.Button(self.topFrame,
          text = 'Roll Again',
          command = self.randomNumber,
          font = ('Garamond', 30))
        self.rollBtn.pack(side = 'left')

    def randomNumber(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        self.display.config(text = str(self.value))


        self.Row1.pack()
        self.Row2.pack()
        self.Row3.pack()
        self.gameFrame.pack()
        self.topFrame.pack()
        self.gameWin.mainloop()

DR = DiceRoller()

DR
```

This is my first time using Tkinter and my first time working with classes, so I feel a bit in over my head.

Basically, when I run the code I get a loading wheel by my pointer, but nothing opens.

I am trying to alter a similar code to create a dice roller, but I cannot tell where the error is just by comparing the two.

Comment: What are you expecting the last line (`DR`) to do?

Comment: `mainloop()` is never called...nor is `randomNumber()`.

Comment: move `self.Row1.pack() ... self.gameWin.mainloop()` to `__init__`